# How do I get the perceived styling of a text node?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[window.getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) method accepts only element nodes. **Is there any way to reliably get the style that determines the visual representation of a text node?**

I realize that nodes can't have `style` attributes, but they certainly are styled, since they inherit the parent element's styles. Is there, perhaps, a way to **get all computed styles from the parent element that are relevant to the text node's visual representation?**

---

Note that wrapping the node in a `span` is out of the question: this would affect CSS rules such as `span:nth-child` or `span + span`, etc.

Comment: instead of <span> you could use <fake>, since it won't have pre-defined styles...

Comment: @dandavis this doesn't prevent the element from changing how CSS rules are applied. For example `:nth-child` selectors could become broken.

Comment: well, there's no easy/perfect way, or it would be suggested by now. i think <fake> gives you the best approximation to what you want. i don't recall seeing, and couldn't find when looking through some big libraries, a `:nth-child` without a tag or class bolted on the front... I think the chance of conflicts would be minute and semi-addressable.  for example, temporarily applying the <fake> only for measurement would keep the look from becoming trashed for more than a few ms, and you could insert an extra node in front then re-compare to filter/detect `parent *:nth-child` rules...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll give it a try myself.

1. Use `window.getComputedStyle()` on the parent element and store the tag name and the style information.
2. Create a new element with the stored tag name and assign the styles to it via `style` attribute.
3. Add a child `<foo>` element (strictly speaking, it should be of a tag name that is not mentioned in the current CSS rules, so that they don't affect it).
4. Attach the parent element to the `<head>` of the document (Webkit-specific).
5. Use `window.getComputedStyle()` on the child element.
6. Set `inline` as the value of `display` property (as text nodes are always inline).

Note the results of the code snippet. `color` is red, `margin-left` is zero, despite the parent having a left margin, and `width` (and `height`, too) is `auto`.

```js
var source = document.querySelector('.bar');
var sourceStyle = window.getComputedStyle(source);
var sourceTag = source.tagName;
var clone = document.createElement(sourceTag);
var child = document.createElement('foo');
var head = document.querySelector('head');

child.innerHTML = 1;
child.setAttribute('style', 'display: inline;');
clone.appendChild(child);
clone.setAttribute('style', sourceStyle.cssText);
head.appendChild(clone);
alert(window.getComputedStyle(source).marginLeft); // 100px
alert(window.getComputedStyle(child).color); // rgb(255, 0, 0);
alert(window.getComputedStyle(child).marginLeft); // 0px
alert(window.getComputedStyle(child).width); // auto
```

```css
.bar {
  color: red;
  margin-left: 100px
  }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>An example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="bar">
      foo
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 10):

If the text node is the *only* node in an element, you could simply use `getComputedStyle()` on its `parentNode`.

However, consider the following:

```css
div {border: 1px solid black;}
```

```html
<div>This <em>is</em> a <strong>test</strong></div>
```

You cannot say that "This" and "a" each have a border.  Would it be accurate to say "This" has top-bottom-left borders, and "a" has top-bottom borders only?  That's questionable.

If you limit yourself to styles that specifically apply to text (color, background, textDecoration, font, etc.), applying `getComputedStyle()` on `parentNode` should always work.

Comment: Is there a reliable way to get only styles that specifically apply to text?

Comment: Yes, just pick out the styles that apply to text.

Comment: Just go through CSS standards and pick out these styles? This seems very unreliable, since standards are prone to change, and humans make mistakes.

Comment: Even that could be tricky.  Styles such as `text-indent` wouldn't apply to individual text nodes.  The four styles I listed (along with their substyles) would be fairly safe.  But styles such as `backgroundImage` wouldn't apply to individual text nodes.

Comment: Note that W3C's CSS standards are unlikely to change (except new styles will probably be added in later versions).

Comment: @RickHitchcock can you check out my answer (see below)?

Comment: The real answer is that text nodes do not have any inherent styling and the question, as presented, is fundamentally flawed.

Comment: ... unless you assume every text node lives in its own [anonymous inline box](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#anonymous), in which case that changes the ball game entirely. In that case, it depends entirely on whether the styles are inherited. You *could* then reliably localize this to just properties that 1) are inherited and 2) apply to inline elements. But I'm not sure if that covers all cases.

Comment: @exizt, wrapping the text node in a span would give you the best access to properties that aren't inheritable – with the caveat you already mentioned (`span:nth-child`, etc.).  Cloning the node and putting it in the `head` like you've done is an interesting solution, so +1 for that.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is, you can't. Styles are applied to the elements and are shaped by their content. The text content of an element is not styled directly because it is just data. The other answers and comments are only suggestions to obtain the styling of the element which isn't what you asked for. So what you are asking for can't be done because there is no styling applied to the data, the text node, of an element.

Comment: Attempted to edit the question so as to make it valid.