# Get font color of clicked text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following example will get the color of the word "Here" when you double click to select it.  I need to get the color when you simply single click inside of it.  I also need a way to get the color the of text which does not have a `<font color=""></font>` tag surrounding it, the rgb value maybe?  Basically, when you single click anywhere on the string, I need get the color of the font of the word you clicked on.  How can this be accomplished?

https://jsfiddle.net/7ng9j49t/

HTML:

`<div contentEditable="true"><font color="gold">Here</font> is some text.</div>`

JS:

```
$('div').mousedown(function() {
  var selected = window.getSelection().focusNode.parentNode;
  var color = $(selected).attr('color');
  console.log(color);
});
```

UPDATE:
Using event.target with css('color') works as I expected:
https://jsfiddle.net/fof2u7L9/

```
$('div').mousedown(function(event) {
    var clicked = event.target;
    var color = $(clicked).css('color');
    console.log(color);
});
```

Comment: Side note, don't use the `<font>` element

Comment: I know and thanks but that is what execcommand / contenteditable / designmode use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the perceived styling of a text node?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30963660/how-do-i-get-the-perceived-styling-of-a-text-node)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [event.target](https://api.jquery.com/event.target):

```
$('div').mousedown(function(evt) {
    var clicked = evt.target;
    var color = $(clicked).attr('color');
    console.log(color);
});
```

Comment: cool thanks!  what about naked text that doesn't have a font wrapper?

Comment: @asdfqwerzxcv `color` would be `undefined` for those, since they would not have any `"color"` attribute

Comment: I'd suggest using `.css('color')` instead. That will grab the color from whatever the container happens to be.

Comment: @J.Titus there is no css color for naked text.

Comment: @MatiasCicero i know that, but i need to get the rgb value or something.

Comment: There is no "naked" text. Even text without an explicit container is a child of `<body>`. Thus it would return `rgb(0,0,0)`.

Comment: you're right, it was returning `undefined` my original way but this way returns `rgb(0,0,0)`

Answer (score 7):

- `<font>` tag is deprecated.
- To get an absolute color, use `window.getComputedStyle()`:

Code:

```
var selected = /* get selected element */;
var color = window.getComputedStyle(selected).getPropertyValue("color");
```

Comment: why does the html 5 designmode, contenteditable, execcommand etc use depreciated tags?

Comment: @asdfqwerzxcv Where exactly?

Comment: @asdfqwerzxcv I do not see the <font> tag. Anyway, my solution is working.

Comment: You'll have to actually try the mozilla developer example there.  Select some text, click the foreColor button, input a color, hit okay, inspect that text to see the html, there you will see that a font tag was inserted.  This is how html 5 contenteditable/designmode works.

Comment: Your solution throws an error on the first click: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null

Comment: @asdfqwerzxcv That's your code. I copypasted the first line from your example.

Comment: @asdfqwerzxcv Okay, I'm not sure why it uses deprecated tags. That might be a bug, never really used contentEditable thing, and never seen people use it too. I'm 100% sure, however, that `<font>` tag is deprecated in HTML5.

Comment: @asdfqwerzxcv Find 1 difference: [your example](https://i.gyazo.com/4a2f6a3a31f1ef332c4b61d32d9e8223.png), [first line in my answer](https://i.gyazo.com/146c88220f0c050f049581cd44a161b2.png)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143720/discussion-between-weary-adventurer-and-asdfqwerzxcv).

Comment: i don't care to chat with you when another solution already works.  i have work to do.

Comment: @asdfqwerzxcv I, however, answered your question, and the answer is correct. You can get the computed color of text with window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue("color")

Comment: sure but getting the event.target in the chosen answer is not only cleaner but also works on the first click

Comment: @asdfqwerzxcv *sigh* That's your problem. Your question is "how to get font color", I answered it. Chosen answer does not work if the color is not explicitly assigned (e. g. extended via class)

Comment: yes it does.  I doubted it in my initial comment but it actual works exactly as expected.  it returns rgb(0,0,0) for text which does not have a wrapper.  that is exactly what i was after, it's perfect.  you could have provided a more complete example in your answer since you feel my implementation of your solution is "my problem"